# How to change Ubuntu LTS 18.04.5 to 18.04.4

Tags: 18.04

I have Ubuntu LTS 18.04.5 in the virtual box. I am wondering how to change to Ubuntu 18.04.4 ?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.4 with all upgrades applied becomes 18.04.5.  The .4 or .5 show the upgrade level (and is more significant if using the HWE kernel as 18.04.4 used the now EOL 5.3 kernel, where as 18.04.5 uses the 5.4 kernel; if using the GA kernel they'll both be 4.15). To go backwards means reverting security fixes and is not a wise move (automatic package tools won't do that anyway; offering only automatic for newer/upgraded packages, so backup restoration is easiest, but still unwise).

Comment: There is no 18.04.4. When you download a new 18.04 you will download 18.04.5.

Comment: Is it possible to remove all updates and get back to 18.04.4 ?

Comment: @engr_john This is an XY problem. What problem do you have that you (almost certainly incorrectly) think that downgrading like this would fix?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 18.04.4 with all upgrades applied becomes 18.04.5.

The *[18.04]*.4 or *[18.04]*.5 shows the upgrade level, and is more significant if using the HWE (*hardware enablement*) kernel as 18.04.4 used the now EOL 5.3 kernel, where as 18.04.5 uses the 5.4 kernel; if using the GA (*general*) kernel they'll both be 4.15.

To go backwards means reverting security fixes and is not a wise move.

Apt/deb package tools won't do that anyway; offering only *automatic* for newer/upgraded packages, so a backup restoration is easiest way to go backwards, but that is still unwise.